# Can external users chat with bots in Google Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

I'm adding external users to Google Chat but apparently they can't communicate with my bot. Can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning on the external chat options via Google Admin Console by following the steps below:

1.) Open Admin Console.

2.) From the Admin console Home page, go to Apps and then Google Workspace and then Google Chat and classic Hangouts.

3.) Click External Chat Settings.

4.) Under Organizational Units, select the domain or organizational unit you want to apply settings to.

5.) Next to the setting you want to change, click Edit "".

6.) Toggle the ff settings on.

- Warn Users
- Chat Externally
- Show Status

7.) Click Save.

### Reference

[Turn on external chat options](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9269229?hl=en)

Comment: This still doesn't work. Apparently external users are unable to chat with Google Chat bots.